# Fazendo requisição http post ao webservice

Tags: angularjs, ionic, http-request

Estou fazendo aqui uma requisição `http` para um webservice `apsh`, para fazer requisição faço assim:

```
validaLogin(user: User) {
    var data = JSON.stringify({ email: user.email, senha: user.senha });

    console.log(data);

    return this.http.post(this.url, data)
        .do(this.logResponde)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.catchError);
}

private catchError(error: Response | any) {
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || "Erro de conexção");
}

private logResponde(res: Response) {
    console.log(res);
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
    return res.json();
}
```

e no `webservice` recebo assim:

```
string email = context.Request.Form["email"];
string senha = context.Request.Form["senha"];
```

Não tenho condições de alterar o `ws` apenas a forma de fazer requisição.

O problema que esta ocorrendo é que está chegando tudo `null`.

Onde estou errando ?

> Estou achando que é questão de `body` ou algo assim.

Comment: Qual é o problema que está acontecendo?

Comment: Ele esta chegando como null

Comment: Pode mostrar como está escrito o método que recebe a requisição?

Comment: Esta na resposta.

Comment: quis dizer o método todo do `webservice`